# Please tell how to solve it and approach such type of difficult questions

Tags: polynomials, quartics

Please tell how to approach such types of questions with a detailed solution (https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Lwl.jpg)

If $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma ,\delta$ are roots of the equation $x^4+ax^2+bx+c=0$

Then find  $$\frac{\alpha^7+\beta^7+\gamma^7+\delta^7}{b(c-a^2)}$$

Comment: apply the quartic formula. plug in 1 for A, 0 for B, a for C, b for D, and c for E

Answer (score 1):

For these type of questions, use the formula :

For a polynomial -

$P(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+.......a_{n-1}x+a_n$

;

$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} a_iS_{r-i}+ra_r=0$

Where ;

$S_r=\sum \alpha_i^r$

And, $\alpha_i$ are roots of polynomial $P(x)=0$

Apply this formula for $r=0,1,2,3...m$ till you get value of $S_m$

If you run out of $a_r$ (when $r>n$) multiply the whole polynomial by $x$ , this will introduce on more root of $P(x)=0$ , but the new root would be $x=0$ so it would have no effect on your $S_m$ ( Since  $0^m$ i.e. $0$ will be added to $S_m$ which will have no effect)

For this question :

$a_0S_r+a_1S_{r-1}+...ra_r=0$

$r=2$

$a_0S_2+a_1S_1+2a_2=0$

Which gives $S_2=-2a$

$r=3$

$a_0S_3+a_1S_2+a_2S_1+3a_3=0$

Which gives $S_3=-3b$

$r=4$ gives $S_4=2a^2-4c$

$r=5$

Multiply $P(x)$ by $x$

$x^5+ax^3+bx^2+cx=0$

Here, put $r=5$

Note : $a_5=0$ here

$a_0S_5+a_1S_4+a_2S_3+a_3S_2+a_4S_1+5a_5=0$

Which gives $S_5 = 5ab$

Now proceed as I have done above.

This method seems to be lengthy, but believe me it's very helpful and short when you practice for it, specially in those type of questions where numerical values are given.

This method also helps in other  problems too, for example

$x+y+z=1$

$x^2+y^2+z^2=2$

$x^3+y^3+z^3=3$

Find : $x^5+y^5+z^5$

Here, assume a cubic equation whose roots are $x,y$ and $z$, and apply the formula I have provided you .This solves the problem in a couple of minutes!

Comment: Pls tell a full answer for better understanding

Comment: Dear friend it was nice to read your answer but as I am a beginner, it seems difficult to me to understand your concept. It would be nice if you will elaborate your answer. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Kamal No worries, what exactly are you not able to understand?Are you a highschool student?(well I am too! I am in 11th Class) Tell me your problem and I will try my best to explain.

Comment: Yes I am in class 10 presently. I am getting difficulty to understand that how did you get the value of S1, S2 and rest other values and how did you get this iSr−i+rar=0

Comment: Ah! Now I understand where is trouble.Since you will study this property of polynomial in 11th standard, you aren't able to use it.Look, I may explain in short.You must have studied that sum of roots of a quadratic equation = -b/a and product = c/a. You have studied this for quadratic, but this rule applies to every polynomial.For a polynomial $\sum a_kx^k$ Sum of the roots taken one at a time is given by $-a_{n-1}/a_{n}$,  Sum of the roots taken two at a time is given by $-a_{n-2}/a_{n}$, and so on.Don't worry you will study all this in 11th standard.

Comment: Till then, hold on or ask your teacher or your elder brother/sister to explain theory of equations in detail.Than you won't have any trouble.I would recommend to not to study now, as your board exams might be going on, focus on that.All the best for boards!

Comment: I am going to post some new questions now. Hope you will solve them

Comment: Don't simply post questions, also tell your thoughts and work on that, this forum doesn't allow simply posting questions.Although you did the same in this one but it may not be continued further.Read the Tour page completely first.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint #1**:  for each root $\alpha^4 = -a \alpha^2 - b \alpha- c\,$, so:

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha^7 & = -a \alpha^5 - b\alpha^4 - c\alpha^3 \\
 & = -a(-a\alpha^3-b\alpha^2-c\alpha) - b(-a \alpha^2 - b \alpha- c)  - c\alpha^3 \\
 & = (a^2-c)\alpha^3 +2ab \alpha^2+(ac+b^2)\alpha+bc
\end{align}
$$

**Hint #2**: the quartic has no $x^3$ term so $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=0\,$. Then, by [Newton's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials) (or direct calculation):

$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2&=-2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma+\beta\delta+\gamma\delta) & = -2a \\
\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+\delta^3 &= 3(\alpha\beta\gamma+\alpha\beta\delta+\alpha\gamma\delta+\beta\gamma\delta) & = -3b
\end{alignat}
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]   **Hint #1+2:**

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\sum \alpha^7 &= (a^2-c)\sum\alpha^3 +2ab \sum\alpha^2+\bcancel{(ac+b^2)\sum\alpha}+4bc \\
 &=(a^2-c)\,(-3b)+2ab\,(-2a)+4bc = \;\cdots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Kamal Edited into the answer. The $\;\cdots\;$ part is just a routine calculation at this point.